# AWS Quicksight - Edit/Tweak auto generated query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

Is there a way to get edit and tweak the Quicksight auto generated query (to Athena) for a dashboard's graph?

For example, an auto generated graph is now timing out because the data volume in the backend increased. This can be solved by using the partition column in the where clause. Since the graph's query to 'Athena' is autogenerated by Quicksight, there is now no way to edit the query and hence tweak it as per my knowledge. Or, am i missing something?

Well, importing the data to SPICE could be an option, but I don't want go that route.

[image: Athena Query timeout]

Comment: timeout mostly happens because of the file sizes.Can you confirm what is the average file size in s3?

Comment: Thats true, but I was wondering if its possible to edit/see the query issued by Quicksight?

Comment: When you do any filter or aggregation in quicksight it will issue a query to Athena in background. You can verify the same in query history in Athena console

Comment: @bdcloud This could be the answer.